# Organize Grep Output

Tags: awk

Need help displaying desired output like my example below. Thanks in advance!

I have this (without the bullets):

```
SWTICH1:interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
SWTICH1: switchport mode access
SWTICH1:interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2
SWTICH1: switchport mode access
SWTICH1:interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3
SWTICH1: switchport mode access
SWTICH1:interface GigabitEthernet1/0/4
SWTICH1: switchport mode access
SWTICH1:interface GigabitEthernet1/0/5
SWTICH1: switchport mode access
SWTICH1:interface GigabitEthernet1/0/6
SWTICH1: switchport mode access

SWTICH2:interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
SWTICH2: switchport mode access
SWTICH2:interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2
SWTICH2: switchport mode access
SWTICH2:interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3
SWTICH2: switchport mode access
SWTICH2:interface GigabitEthernet1/0/4
SWTICH2: switchport mode access
SWTICH2:interface GigabitEthernet1/0/5
SWTICH2: switchport mode access
SWTICH2:interface GigabitEthernet1/0/6
SWTICH2: switchport mode access
```

I want it to be like this (without the bullets):

```
SWTICH1:
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
switchport mode access
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2
switchport mode access
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3
switchport mode access
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/4
switchport mode access
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/5
switchport mode access
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/6
switchport mode access
SWTICH2:
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
switchport mode access
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2
switchport mode access
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3
switchport mode access
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/4
switchport mode access
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/5
switchport mode access
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/6
switchport mode access
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, it is always recommended to wrap your samples in code tags see `{}` button. Also it is always recommended to post your efforts which you have put in order to fix your own problem too.

Comment: Noted and thank you

Comment: Sure, please try my code once and let us know if it is working?

Comment: Worked like a charm sir. :) Thank you so much!

Comment: Which command did you use to generate this output. It looks like a grep and the tags `SWITCH1` and `SWITCH2` are filenames. If this is the case, we can just update your grep command to get rid of that. (the flag `-h` does that. See `man grep`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***EDIT:*** As per ghoti sir's comment adding a solution which will give output in order of switch keyword  and should work in any `awk`  too.

```
awk -F':' '
NF{
  sub(/^ +/,"",$2)
}
!b[$1]++{
  c[++count]=$1
}
{
  a[$1]=(a[$1]?a[$1] ORS $2:$2)
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print c[i] ORS a[c[i]]
  }
}'  Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following, looks like `awk` could be good fit for this question.

```
awk -F':' 'NF{sub(/^ +/,"",$2);a[$1]=(a[$1]?a[$1] ORS $2:$2)} END{for(i in a){print i ORS a[i]}}' Input_file
```

Explanation: Adding explanation here.

```
awk -F':' '                        ##Setting field separator as colon here.
NF{                                ##Checking if NF value is NOT NULL where NF is number of fields in current line.
  sub(/^ +/,"",$2)                 ##Using sub function of awk which substitutes all initial/starting space from $2(second field) with NULL.
  a[$1]=(a[$1]?a[$1] ORS $2:$2)    ##Creating an array named a whose index is first field of current line and concatenating $2 values to its previous value.
}                                  ##Closing block for NF condition here.
END{                               ##Starting END condition of awk command here.
  for(i in a){                     ##Starting a for loop to traverse through array a here.
    print i ORS a[i]               ##Printing index of array a which is variable i now and ORS(new line) and then value of array a whose index is variable i.
  }                                ##Closing block for for loop here.
}'  Input_file                     ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: One catch with this solution is that when using `for(i in a)` does not necessarily return array indices in the same order they were added. For example: `'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<10;i++)a[i];for(i in a)print i}'` .. looks ordered correctly in gawk, but not in mawk or bsd awk. To get around this and preserve order, you'd need an additional array with a numbered index whose values are the indices of `a[]`.

Comment: @ghoti, to be honest I usually add this kind of solution, added it now(will add non-one liner form of solution too now), thanks for mentioning sir.

Comment: Excellent update, that does the trick. :-)  For future reference, you may be able to avoid requiring the `count` variable by using `length(b)`. While this behaviour isn't [defined in POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html), in practice it works in gawk, mawk, and the One True Awk and its derivatives (like BSD awk).

Answer (score 0):

A simple `awk` solution might look like this:

```
awk -F: 'length() && $1!=s {s=$1;print s} {print $2}' input.txt
```

This works by capturing the first colon-separated "field", and if it's different from the previous line, printing it ... and then printing the second "field", which is your content.  If you want the output to match more precisely, it's easy enough:

```
awk -F: 'length() && $1!=s {s=$1;print s ":"} length() {gsub(/^ /,"",$2);print $2}' input.txt
```

We use `length()` as a condition because otherwise the `$1!=s` test will match blank lines.

Alternately, you could do this in bash alone, implementing similar logic:

```
while IFS=: read a b; do [[ -n "$a" ]] && [[ $s != $a ]] && s="$a" && printf '%s:\n' "$s"; printf '%s\n' "${b## }"; done < input.txt
```

Or for easier reading:

```
while IFS=: read a b; do
  if [[ -n "$a" ]] && [[ $s != $a ]]; then
    s="$a"
    printf '%s:\n' "$s"
  fi
  printf '%s\n' "${b## }"
done < input.txt
```

I've included the more complex formatting in this one.

Comment: Thank you sir, I used this and it worked also. Appreciate your effort on helping out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another awk

```
$ awk -F: ' { if($1!=p) { print $1; p=$1; }  $1=""; print }' bantay.txt
SWTICH1
 interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
  switchport mode access
 interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2
  switchport mode access
 interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3
  switchport mode access
 interface GigabitEthernet1/0/4
  switchport mode access
 interface GigabitEthernet1/0/5
  switchport mode access
 interface GigabitEthernet1/0/6
  switchport mode access


SWTICH2
 interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
  switchport mode access
 interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2
  switchport mode access
 interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3
  switchport mode access
 interface GigabitEthernet1/0/4
  switchport mode access
 interface GigabitEthernet1/0/5
  switchport mode access
 interface GigabitEthernet1/0/6
  switchport mode access

$
```